# Paypal. button in bootstrap 5 accordion

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

I have an accordion with some items. Now I want to show a paypal pay button in each accordion item. I am using the paypal JS SDK. So for it is working just for the first open accordion item. There the paypal button is shown, I can click on it and paypal modal is opening to login and pay.

I have created a file where I have added the "paypal-button-container" and included a PHP file with the paypal JS script:

```
<?php                                            
include_once ('method/paypal_accordion.php');
?>
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
```

In the included file 'method/paypal_accordion.php' I have the paypal script with the variables for the payment:

```
<script>
    // Loop over each funding source/payment method
    var FUNDING_SOURCES = [
        paypal.FUNDING.PAYPAL
    ];

    FUNDING_SOURCES.forEach(function(fundingSource) {
        // Initialize the buttons
        var button = paypal.Buttons({
            fundingSource: fundingSource,
            createOrder: function (data, actions) {
                return actions.order.create({
                    application_context: {
                        brand_name: 'my-page.com',
                        locale: 'en_gb',
                        shipping_preference: 'SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS',
                    },
                    intent: 'CAPTURE',
                    payer: {
                        email_address: '<?php echo $email; ?>',
                    ...
                     onApprove: function (data, actions) {
                     return actions.order.capture().then(function (orderData) {
                     ...
                      });
            },
```

How can the paypal button be shown on every opened accordion item?
Currently I just see the paypal div there, but no button:

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
```

Should I reload the DOM or is there an event in the accordion to do that?
Or should I use a button with a form or some AJAX?

Comment: It sounds like you could be using multiple id's with the same name in your HTML code, id's have to be unique.

Comment: Thank you. You mean I should use a unique-id here: `<div id="paypal-button-container-<unique-id>"></div>`?

Comment: Not just there, [any id in your HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp) needs to be unique, always. But, yes, that was the id I was talking about. 

Answer (score 0):

- Each div where you want to render a PayPal button must have a unique `id`
- Each time you invoke `paypal.Buttons({...})` and call `.render('#some-id-goes-here')`, the selector to render in should be one of those ids.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. It brought me on the right track. Now it is solved.